# Add and remove Form Inputs dynamically react native

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, use-state, dynamic-forms

I am already able to add the inputs correctly but when I try to delete it deletes but does not add again what I am doing wrong ??

I am having the following error:

Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator] () method.

```
function handleAddInput() {
    setInput([...input, <FormGroup />]);
  }

  function handleDeleteInput() {
    if (input.length > 0) {
      setInput([...input, input] - 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      
            <FormContainer ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSignUpFinally}>
              {selectedValue === 'Sim' ? (
                <>
                  <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize="words"
                    name="full_name"
                    icon="user"
                    placeholder="Nome completo"
                  />

                  <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    name="cpf"
                    icon="user"
                    placeholder="CPF"
                  />

                  <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    name="phone"
                    icon="phone"
                    placeholder="Celular"
                  />

                  {input.map !== undefined && input.map(item => item)}

                  {input.length > 0 && (
                    <Button
                      onPress={handleDeleteInput}
                      style={{ marginBottom: 8, backgroundColor: '#f31' }}
                    >
                      Remover integrante
                    </Button>
                  )}

                  <Button
                    onPress={() => handleAddInput(input.length)}
                    style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
                  >
                    Adicionar integrante
                  </Button>
```

Comment: Your delete sets `input` to `[...input, input] - 1`, which is `NaN`. It also helps to name things appropriately. The name of an array should be a plural noun like `inputs`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so how can I delete it?

Comment: No idea because I don't know what `[...input, input] - 1` is supposed to do. `[...input, input]` doesn't make any sense for deletion either. You have to determine what it should do.

Comment: I need to add or delete input fields from a button input is my array of FormGroup @AluanHaddad

Comment: Look up how to remove remove an item from an array.